# weekview calendar

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, icalendar

Is there a simple weekView calendar that we can integrate to our iPhone application? The iCal contains only month view and from what i searched on net, I get only month view calendars.

Help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at this: [calendar-ui](https://github.com/muhku/calendar-ui)

Simple to use and quite well done.